# Need a solution for a PHP endless loop problem

Tags: php

I want to loop this code until it prints the last value which is 51 as a single value. when I change starting value (1) and ending value (51 -> 1) to 2 and 4 it works fine.

But if the starting = ending value again this endless loop occurs.

```
$path = "1/40/51/"; 
while ($path != "") {

    $arr = explode("/", $path);
    $value = $arr[0];
    echo '</br>';
    echo $value;
    

    $path = str_replace($value. '/', '', $path);
    echo '</br>';
    echo $path;
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: HTML side note: `</br>` is not a valid tag. `<br/>` or `<br />` or `<br>` are.

Comment: What does this have to do with mysqli/phpmyadmin? You tagged as such. Edit: Someone edited those out. I am just wondering why you used those to begin with.

Comment: Why are you doing it like this? Why not just `foreach (explode("/", $path) as $value)`?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Let me guess: the `$path` value came from a database query.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner sorry.. my bad thank you for notifying me.

Comment: @Barmar yes bro it comes from my database. I just set a dummy value to this path

Comment: @Jeto I need to print each and every single vale from a long path like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `$value == "1"`, `$value . "/"` matches `1/` at the beginning of the string, but it also matches `1/` at the end of `51/`. So when you do the `str_replace()`, the result is `40/5`.

The loop assumes that every number will be followed by `/`, but after that replacement it's no longer true for the last number. As a result, the replacements never remove everything, so you never reach the end condition of the loop.

Your algorithm won't work when there's a number that ends with an earlier number.

If you want to print each number in the string, just use a `foreach` loop.

```
foreach (explode('/', $path) as $value) {
    if (!empty($value)) { // skip the empty value after the last `/`
        echo "<br>$value";
    }
}
```

Comment: I was just about to write a similar explanation. I don't know why, but I've seen so many people try to invent algorithms based on replacing when that's not at all what the end goal is. Don't fall into that trap.

Comment: I left out a `}`

Comment: @Barmar need one last help how do I access the last value ( $value ) from out side the loop?

Comment: Assign another variable inside the `if`. `$last_value = $value;`

Comment: If you're storing lists in the database like this, you should consider normalizing your design. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Answer (score 2):

SUGGESTION:

1. Get out a pencil and paper
2. Write down what you expect "$path" to equal after the first `$path = str_replace($value. '/', '', $path);`
3. Write down the expected values of "$path" after the second and third loops
4. Q: does "$path" ever become ""?
5. Q: If not, why not?